# Microsoft.Office365.OAuth.Xamarin breaks Android build

Tags: android, xamarin, office365, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms (1.3-pre1) application, which needs to integrate with Office 365. In my Android project, my build breaks when I reference the NuGet package in subject (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OAuth.Xamarin/)

After this package is referenced, I get following error at the end of my build:

`3>  UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    3>  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/util/TimeUtils;
    3>      at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
    3>      at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    3>      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    3>      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    3>      at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:279)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    3>      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    3>  1 error; aborting
    3>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1243,3): error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1.
    3>Done executing task "CompileToDalvik" -- FAILED.
    3>Done building target "_CompileDex" in project "KwhApp.Forms.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.
    3>
    3>Build FAILED.`

Removing the package reference, I get my build to complete instead.

Anyone having the same issue? Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of the Microsoft.Office365.OAuth.Xamarin package do you have installed?

Comment: Latest one available atm: version 1.0.22

Answer (score 1):

Ah ok. I checked with the engineering folks, and they're aware of the issue. Details (and a workaround) here: http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/getting-started-with-office-365-apis-and-xamarin-projects/.

Comment: I was already looking into that. I initially had some problems in building the Android solution also there, but I now succeeded by replacing and using the proper packages. Thank you for your quick reaction

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem after update android packages.

My solution was opening packages.config in Android project and remove android support v4 from xml:

```
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid70" />
```

After that, I go to package folder. and add it again from nuget. When I do that, new Android packages was added. And project build and run again.

Hope this help.